# Uniform bound for Bessel functions

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

In NIST the following bound is claimed: $|J_\nu(x)|\le 1$ for all $x,\nu\ge0$. This is trivial for integer $\nu$, and it is pretty easy to prove a bound with 1 replaced, say, by 2. Does anyone have a reference for the sharp bound 1?

EDIT: let me clarify that the bound is true, and it follows e.g. by applying a bound by Landau $|J_\nu(x)|\le 0.79|x|^{-1/3}$ for $x>2$, plus a more standard estimate for $x<2$. I am looking for a simpler and more natural proof; I guess it should exist, since NIST does not even bother to give a reference for it.

Comment: do u know what happens in [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/JAA.2006.83/html?lang=en) (I don't)?

Comment: Yes, it's a nice paper on sharp asymptotic bounds. Let me add that the bound can be proved by applying results from a related paper by Landau. But the claim from NIST is earlier and should be easier to prove (I guess!)

Comment: Indeed a quadratic exponential decay of $J_\nu$ seems a bit too much. Certainly the estimate refers to a restricted interval of $x$

Comment: Watson p. 406 equation (10) and preceding statement. Watson cites [Lommel, Münchener Abh. xv. (1886), pp. 561-563](https://publikationen.badw.de/de/003083022/pdf/CC%20BY), [metadata](https://badw.de/publikationen.html?tx_badwdb_publications%5Baction%5D=show&tx_badwdb_publications%5Bcontroller%5D=Publications&tx_badwdb_publications%5Bpub_id%5D=10896&cHash=edf0e88d352563e896144937d45b76fc). There is also a related note on p. 152.